# iOS 14 getAllVoiceShortcuts returning LaunchServices errors

Tags: ios14, sirishortcuts

In a completely blank Xcode project, I simply call:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.getAllVoiceShortcuts { (shortcuts, error) in
        }
    }
}
```

It fails with this log:

```
[default] LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=271, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
```

This is retried 20 times until it gives up.

Siri Capability was added to the App. Happens only on physical device in iOS 14 GM and Xcode 12 GM.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm also getting this error with 10 retries when I load a `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton` so it seems like an issue with SiriKit in general, but I haven't found a good workaround yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem (as you said, only in physical device), but I have 10 retries, not 20.
Before iOS 14.0 I had no errors, so maybe it is some bug in SiriKit.
I noticed that this is happens only once - when you call this next time, there are no errors.
So, for now, I added this call in AppDelegate - when app is starting, because that errors freeze UI for a second.